# Swift Decode not working if setter & getter used

Tags: swift, serialization, core-data, decode, encode

The last couple of evenings I have been trying to work through an issue, but got nowhere.

The summary issue is as follows: If I have standard public properties in my class and encode the data to then be stored in Core Data, everything works fine.  If I then amend the class so that it has a getter and setter explicitly defined (with a private variable) then the encode doesn't seem to work and so the decode fails when fetching the data back from Core Data.

Here is the class I am having a problem with:

```
import Foundation

class MapLocation: NSObject, NSCoding {

// MARK: - Properties

// If section 1 below is used (and section 2 commented out) everything works fine. If section 2 below is used (and section 1 commented out) encode seems to fail for core data.

// Section 1 Start

public var row: Int!
public var column: Int!

// Section 1 End

// Section 2 Start

public var row: Int {
    get {
        return self._row
    } set {
        self._row = newValue
        landType = MapLayout.landTypeForLocation(row: _row, column: _column)
    }
}
public var column: Int {
    get {
        return self._column
    } set {
        self._column = newValue
        landType = MapLayout.landTypeForLocation(row: _row, column: _column)
    }
}

// MARK: - Instance variables

private var _row: Int = 0
private var _column: Int = 0

// Section 2 End

public var landType: LandType!

// MARK: - Constructors

override init() {

    super.init()

    // Game Starting location
    self.row = 3
    self.column = 4

    self.landType = MapLayout.landTypeForLocation(row: self.row, column: self.column)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init()

    guard let row = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.playerLocationRow) as? Int,
        let column = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.playerLocationColumn) as? Int
        else {
            print("SVL Error: decoding failed MapLocation")
            return nil
    }

    self.row = row
    self.column = column

    self.landType = MapLayout.landTypeForLocation(row: row, column: column)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encode(row, forKey: PropertyKey.playerLocationRow)
    aCoder.encode(column, forKey: PropertyKey.playerLocationColumn)
  }
}
```

In a separate class I store the 'parent' class 'Player' which has the above class as a property:

```
   playerEntity.properties = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: player, requiringSecureCoding: false) ...
```

And then retrieve the saved values from Core Data using:

```
   if let returnPlayer = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(playerPropertiesData) as? Player {...
```

When section 2 is uncommented, I get the following in the console log:
"SVL Error: decoding failed MapLocation" 
This is because the 'guard let row = ' section of the decoder init method fails to decode the object and so calls the Exception.

Interestingly, if I use section 1 of the code to 'save' into coredata and then use section 2 of the code to 'load' the data, everything works fine.  Which makes me think it is the encoding that is the issue (even though the issue appears at the decoding point).

It's so strange that such a minor change causes it to pass/fail, but hoping someone out there has experienced this anomoly before. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated but there are no backing instance variables in Swift. Remove the private variables starting with an underscore and use the `didSet` observer.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was the setting of the private instance variables (_row and _column) to = 0 that was breaking everything.

Changed that and it all worked correctly.

Posting this answer in case anyone else pulls their hair out for 2 evenings like I did :-)